# Application won't run/open on other computer

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio-2012, adb

I created a basic toolkit in .EXE format with ADB and Fastboot commands for my phone in Visual Studio Express 2012 using C#, and it works great on my computer, but when I try and open it on another computer, nothing happens. I have made sure to build it in Release mode, the computers I have tested are all on Windows 8 and have the latest .NET Frameworks, and I have read many other topics on this with no definitive answers. I am also getting errors in Event Viewer, but I'm not exactly sure what they mean. Have a look if you can, and thanks!

.NET Runtime:

`Application: HTC One X+ Toolkit.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at HTC_One_X__Toolkit.Form1.InitializeComponent()
   at HTC_One_X__Toolkit.Form1..ctor()
   at HTC_One_X__Toolkit.Program.Main()`

Application Error:

`Faulting application name: HTC One X+ Toolkit.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x51bf3a29
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16451, time stamp: 0x50988950
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014b32
Faulting process id: 0x1a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce6b7ca5512761
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Dylan\Downloads\Toolkit (2)\Toolkit\HTC One X+ Toolkit.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: e3254e0e-d76f-11e2-be89-50465d351325
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:`

Windows Error Reporting:

`Fault bucket -606412384, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: htc one x+ toolkit.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 51bf3a29
P4: 5
P5: 1.0.0.0
P6: 51bf3a29
P7: 13
P8: 6
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P10:

Attached files:
C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF566.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_htc one x+ toolk_e8ec446f1f71f1db9137fab138c0ad59c2ef6a1_1abaf806

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: e3254e0e-d76f-11e2-be89-50465d351325
Report Status: 16
Hashed bucket: 93c40e517fd84a9afa8e9156e3471d7b `

Comment: I would look at putting a try catch around your code in your `Main()` method and presenting that exception to the screen. that way you can provide yourself some more information.

Answer (score 0):

it's seems by the look of the stack trace that the code generated by the .net framework is trying to open a file from absolute location rather then a relative location. have you looked over the InitializeComponent method in the class Form1?
if not, please have a look. if you can't find a problem there wrep the call for InitializeComponent in try catch in order to get more information.
i would also recommend to try and debug it on other computer and go step by step. you can attach to a process using the visual studio and pause your program until the user pressed a button (using a message box for example)